# Ms Access database student rank for same mark

Tags: sql, ms-access, rank

I have a table like this :

```
### Table name: studentresult ###
Name    Cls Roll Mark result Rank
Jubayer 10  1    600  Pass 
Jewel   10  2    620  Pass
James   10  3    590  Pass
Jemi    10  4    590  Pass
Kalis   10  5    449  Fail
Lelin   10  6    600  Pass
```

I want to generate the ranks of the students automatically. The rank will depend on the mark (higher mark implies better rank). If two students (or more) have the same mark, the roll will determine the relative ranking (lower roll implies better rank). Finally, if a student has failed, he will not be considered in the ranking.

In my example, the result would be like this :

```
Name   Cls Roll Mark result Rank
Jubayer 10  1   600  Pass   2
Jewel   10  2   620  Pass   1
James   10  3   590  Pass   4
Jemi    10  4   590  Pass   5
Kalis   10  5   449  Fail  **
Lelin   10  6   600  Pass   3
```

Comment: If you use and extra column then you can do it easily. Extra column means a helper column just for calculation.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
name,
Cls,
Roll,
Mark,
CASE WHEN t.result LIKE 'Pass' THEN a.pos+1
WHEN t.result LIKE 'Fail' THEN '**'
END as Rank

FROM table t
CROSS JOIN (SELECT posexplode(split(repeat(',', 70), ','))) a
ORDER BY t.Roll
```

This wil create 70 rows if you have 70 students.

Comment: Is the answer will work to `MS-Access` database? I think it is for `MSSQL` server.

Answer (score 0):

In MS Access, you can use a correlated subquery:

```
select sr.*,
       iif(sr.result = "Pass",
           (select count(*)
            from studentresult as sr2
            where sr2.result = "Pass" and
                  (sr2.Mark > sr.Mark or
                   sr2.Mark = sr.Mark and sr2.roll <= sr.roll
                  )
           ),
           NULL
       ) as ranking
from studentresult as sr;
```

Note that this uses `NULL` for the missing value for fails.  This is much more convenient than `'**'`.  You can use the latter but you need to convert the number to a string so the entire column is a string.  `NULL` just works.

Comment: This not work properly . Parameter is found and fail student also in rank. This is not acceptable

Comment: @Jewel . . . No, the failed students are not in the ranking.  That is what `sr2.result = "Pass"` does.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Failed students are not ranking but duplicate mark ranking are coming as duplicate. For mark `590` rankings are showing 5,5.

Comment: @Harun24HR . . . There was a typo in the query.  The correlation condition was only referring to one table, not two.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I think still there is typo in `sr2.roll <= sr1.roll`. It will be `sr2.roll <= sr.roll`. There is no `alis` with name `sr1`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the generic function *RowRank* from my project [RowNumbers](https://github.com/GustavBrock/VBA.RowNumbers).

Too much code to post here, but go to paragraph **5. Rank** for the details.

**Example**:

A bit tricky as *Mark* is sorted *Desc* while *Roll* is sorted *Asc*:

```sql
SELECT 
    studentresult.Name, 
    studentresult.Cls, 
    studentresult.Roll, 
    studentresult.Mark, 
    studentresult.Pass, 
    IIf([Pass]='Pass',RowRank("[Mark],-[Roll]","(select * from studentresult where Pass='Pass')",[Mark],-[Roll],2),Null) AS Rank
FROM 
    studentresult;
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Can I contact with you ? I can't solve.plz send me this project file to my email. Email: jubayer.jewel@gmail.com

Comment: Can I contact with you by email.

Comment: Sir, i have check it. This not work properly when 2 more same number  appear then rank will show 0 . It is a big problem .

Answer (score 0):

I have just modify the code of Mr. GordonLinoff answers. Try below query...

```
SELECT sr.*, IIf(sr.result="Pass",(select count(*)
            from Table1 as sr2
            where sr2.result = "Pass" and
                  (sr2.Mark*10000-sr2.roll >= sr.Mark*10000-sr.roll and sr2.roll = sr2.roll
                  )
           ),Null) AS ranking
FROM Table1 AS sr;
```

[image]

Comment: Can I contact with you by email or messenger or fb.?

Comment: Yes you can. harun24hr@gmail.com and facebook profile is harun24hr